# Python 3.4.2 | NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a word based maze game in Python 3.4.2, and I am having problems with this error message when I try to run it: `NameError: name 'direction' is not defined`

This is how I have defined it:

```
def chooseDirection():
    direction = input('''What way will you go? (Type Left or Right or Forward then press enter.) ''')
```

Then I tried using 'direction' this way:

```
if direction == str(Right or right):
    print ('Congrats! You have turned the right way, you can live...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('For now o.O')
```

I can't find any issues with my code, and I have checked some other similar questions from stackoverflow, but none have worked.

[Here is my full code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:46e9)

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated and let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks, Sebastian.

Comment: Please paste your full code on the question. Do not use links to external pages for code.

Comment: I would say you need to read a good tutorial on Python. Or change to some other from the current you're using, because apparently it's no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def checkDirection(chooseDirection):

print('You have now entered the maze.')
time.sleep(0.5)

if direction == str(Right or right):
print ('Congrats! You have turned the right way, you can live...')
time.sleep(1)
print ('For now o.O')
```

replace direction with chooseDirection because that is the argument you are trying to pass ( or take the value)

for if else if you use

```
if (direction == 'Right' or direction == 'Left'):
```

Also

```
def chooseDirection():
direction = input('''What way will you go? (Type Left or Right or Forward then press enter.) ''')

return chooseDirection
```

I think you want to return direction, not chooseDirection.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was going to be something very obvious, but I still really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. You really need to read a good tutorial on Python.

For correction your code;

First of all you should change checkDirection parameter to `direction`. You do not have `direction` variable in `checkDirection` method.

```
def checkDirection(direction):
    ...
```

Also you do not handle return value of `chooseDirection` method.

Inside `while` loop you should put it a variable and call `checkDirection` with it

```
d = chooseDirection()
checkDirection(d)
```

Finally `chooseDirection` not return correct variable. It should be `direction`